# How to pass a variable (ui object) in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, testing, dart, integration

im a very newbie to flutter integration testing. For now I only know how to write basic sheets of finding elements on a screen and make some actions to them.

Can please anyone help me on how to pass a variable in a function if i want to reuse it? Example:

```html
static Future<void> createProjectFromWizard(FlutterDriver driver, String projectName, bool direct) async {

    final faker = new Faker();
    
    final buttonStart = find.byValueKey(OnboardingIds.buttonStart);
    await driver.waitFor(buttonStart).then((_) => driver.tap(buttonStart));
```

I want to reuse this function but instead of final buttonStart I need to find another ui-button. How can I do this without re-writing this function? (Because it is a very long one, i pasted a short piece)

Comment: I guess, I do not understand the question, but why don't you pass the key of the button as an argument to the function?

Comment: Can you provide more information and code? It's still confusing